# passing arguments to zend partial and zend partialLoop

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'll try to describe this as best as possible, i haven't encountered this problem before but maybe i'm doing something wrong.

In my controller: i have:

```
public function indexAction() {
       $this->view->projects = $this->projects->getProjects();
    }
```

In the view file corresponding to this controller i have:

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partials/sidebar/_home.phtml', array($this->projects)); ?>
```

My _home.phtml contains the current code:

```
<div class="sidebar-content">
    <p class="sidebar-title">Projects Portfolio</p>
    <div id='coin-slider' style="margin:0 auto;">
        <?php echo $this->partialLoop('partials/sidebar/_projects-slideshow.phtml', $this->projects);?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my _projects-slideshow.phtml has this code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl($this->pimage); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl($this->pimage); ?>" alt="1" />
    <span>
        <?php echo $this->pname . ' by ' . $this->group . '. Client: ' . $this->client; ?>
    </span>
</a>
```

The problem is that the variable is not passed to `_home.phtml`. I tried a `Zend_Debug::dump($this->projects)` and the result was NULL. I tried a `Zend_Debug::dump($this)` and I found the projects array. What am I doing wrong? The variable is not being passed, or maybe it is, to _home.phtml, not to mention that `_projects-slideshow.phtml` has no idea what `$this->projects` is.

Answer (score 6):

If $this->projects in your _home.phtml is empty I think you should change

in **index.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partials/sidebar/_home.phtml', array($this->projects)); ?>
```

into

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partials/sidebar/_home.phtml', array('projects' => $this->projects)); ?>
```

Comment: I cannot get variables defined in 2nd param array('varName'=>'someValue') - may you know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here how it should has been:

```
  $variables = array (
  'records' => $result
  );

  $this->view->partial ("nodes/relations.php", $variables);
```

The variables in the array are named. What exactly is in your `$this->projects->getProjects()` ?